# Select Join From 2 table wich one of the table has array value of key from another table

Tags: mysql, arrays, join, left-join

I have 2 table :

Table A

```
|id  | Name   |
--------------
|P001| Samsung|
|P002| Nokia  |
|P003| Oppo  |
```

Table B

```
|id   |      Value       |
--------------------------
|1    | P001,P002,P003  |
```

I need a query to generate the view below

```
|id   |          Value       |
------------------------------
|1    | Samsung,Nokia,Oppo  |
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: This is going to be (almost) impossible to do on SQL Server, and very ugly even on MySQL 8+.  You should avoid storing CSV data like this.

Comment: @Zhorov : Mysql

Comment: @harisj OK, I removed the `sqls-server` tag.

Comment: Does the values in CSV (table B) may really contain a space after a comma? *I have 2 table* Provide them as precise CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina not space after comma

Comment: I see a space between comma and P003 in source and between comma and Oppo in output. If "no space" then edit your sample in the question text.

Comment: @Akina that not main problem in this post, the problem is , how to make query to get the result. :)

Comment: *that not main problem in this post* This **is critical**. If your CSV does **not** contain these parasite spaces then simple method (FIND_IN_SET) exists, but it is not applicable when spaces exists.

Comment: @Akina Oke so assumed : 
1. contain space after comma what the query ? ,
2.And assumed thera are not space after comma than what the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2.And assumed thera are not space after comma than what the query ?

```
SELECT b.id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) value
FROM a
JOIN b ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.value)
GROUP BY b.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f684f90dc602d936055f5f5adb96d8a9) (with demonstration that the space after a comma presence result in incorrect output, and possible correction).

Of course, `a.id` must **not** contain commas and/or spaces.

Also you may add `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.value)` clause to `GROUP_CONCAT()` if the order of translated names is important.

Comment: Thanks, Great problem solve.